# Showing ellipsis only for 2nd table row

Tags: html, css

Here is my current situation: https://jsfiddle.net/rhercb/a4b2L95n/

Code:

```css
.house_info_table {
  width: 100%;
}

.house_info_table td {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="house_info_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="">TEST DU:</td>
    <td class="">xxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEST DU:</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Awailable thing here:</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEST DU:</td>
    <td>xxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEST DU:</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can only get both of these columns to shrink, but i need my 1st one to stay like that and not to bounce text in other row, and my 2nd one to show ellipsis when i shrink the page.

[image]

Comment: why not use `min-width`? And why aren't you using `flex` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nth-child` pseudoselector:

```
.house_info_table td {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.house_info_table td:nth-child(2) {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: The one what @elena provided worked, but this one seems more practical and better, thanks.

Comment: @Rhercb So it's OK then that the text gets hidden on resize?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `min-width` together with `width`. Is this what you want?

```css
.house_info_table {
  width: 100%;
}

.house_info_table td {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.first-part {
  min-width: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table class="house_info_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="first-part">TEST DU:</td>
    <td class="">xxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-part">TEST DU:</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-part">Awailable thing here:</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-part">TEST DU:</td>
    <td>xxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-part">TEST DU:</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```